# What is the concept of creating class instance using interface name?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, object-oriented-analysis

what is the concept of set variable or object or i don't know what it's called when i create instance of class and putting in left hand the name of interface,,, I Know that we can't create and object of type interface.

Only I need more clarification what this process named or what is the details done by .Net when I declare these type of object.

```
IDataReader oSQLReader = new SqlDataReader();
IDataReader oOLEReader = new OleDbDataReader();
```

Comment: Try and look up [Polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: this is basic OO practice, you will write methods that only use the interface type as formal parameters and don't care about the concrete object passed as actual parameters. reason for doing this is that if later on you decide to use another concrete class, for example an OracleDataReader, you won't need to change anything in the methods or code which are dealing with the IDataReader only.

Comment: thanks all for the response, Yes I Know that is the Polymorphism but what we called this step?

Comment: I mean when i make SqlDataReader oSqlDataReader = new SqlDataReader() we say that we create new object of type SqlDataReader, when we make IDataReader oSqlDataReader = new SqlDataReader(); we cant say we create object of type IDataReader...  @Davide Piras

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens exactly is that you are creating an instance of the specific class, then you are **upcasting** the reference to the type of the interface.

The type of the reference defines what you can access in the instance. You can only use members of the class that the interface knows about.

The actual type of the object is still the type of the instance that you created, so you can downcast the reference to that type again:

```
SqlDataReader reader = (SqlDataReader)oSQLReader;
```

Comment: I understand from this answer that if we have interface contains two method GetName(); and GetID(); and we have class implements this interface and have another method named GetGender(); if we create object using the up-casting methodology we can only access method that impliminting using interface.. is that right? @Guffa , thanks for the answer and and I will try it now by example :)

Comment: @KhaledQuestions: Yes, that is correct. To access members that exist in the class but not the interface, you need to downcast the reference (or cast it to a different interface that the class also implements and that defines that member).

Answer (score 0):

concept is simple:

```
public class Cat : IAnimal {
     public void Voice() {//implements IAnimal's method
         Console.WriteLine("Miyaoo");
     }
}

public class Dog: IAnimal {
     public void Voice() {  //implements IAnimal's method
         Console.WriteLine("Woof");
     }
}

public interface IAnimal {
      public void Voice();
}
```

after initialization

```
IAnimal animal1 = new Cat(); 
IAnimal animal2 = new Dog();
```

and somewhere in the code

```
public void MakeAnimalSound(IAnimal animal) {
   animal.Voice(); 
}
```

so you can do something like this:

```
MakeAnimalSound(animal1); //prints "Mew" even if type is IAnimal
MakeAnimalSound(animal2); //prints "Woof" even if type is IAnimal
```

*This is polymorphism*.

Answer (score 0):

The concept here is to accomplish the design principle "Program to an interface, not to implementation".

Here the interface can be an abstract class or the actual interface. The concrete class will have the actual implementation which are being exposed to outside world through interfaces.
The client code will access the functionality using interface ,preventing them to directly create an object of concrete class, just giving them access through interface object.

This is accomplished by OO design patterns I believe.